# Unable to synchronize tags from original remote (github)

Tags: git

I've forked a project in github.

I've added both original and cloned remote locally.

I'm able to checkout/pull an updated master from original:

```
git checkout -b original-master original/master
```

However, I'm unable to get new tags from `original`

I've tried

```
git fetch --all 
git fetch original
git checkout -b new-tag original/new-tag
```

I don't see `new-tag` with `git tag` and I get an error:

fatal: 'original/new-tag' is not a commit and a branch 'new-tag' cannot be created from it.

Am I doing something wrong or something get broken locally and I need a fresh clone?

It might be relevant that I'm working on Windows and some pathes might be too long, but then I should get errors by checkout?

Comment: Have you tried `git fetch --tags`?  Depending on the project and how they cut their releases, you may not get the tags by default--Git will only fetch them if there is a traceable path from an existing branch to the tag.  The only other way to get them is by asking for them specifically (`git fetch --tags`) or by updating the fetch refspec to add another line to your .git/config grab them (you'd add `fetch = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` in addition to the `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` that is already there).

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I thought yes, but I didn't. I was following the google results for 'fetch all tags' which suggested using 'fetch --all'. 
Could you make an answer from your comment, possibly shortly explaining, why fetch -all sometimes doesn't fetch tags, if possible?

Comment: BTW, tags aren't generally scoped to a remote... they're only in the global namespace by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the project and how they cut their releases and do tagging, you may not get the tags by default when cloning--Git will only fetch them if there is a traceable path from an existing branch to the tag.  `git fetch --all` won't do the trick either since that only says "fetch all remotes" instead of "fetch all objects".

The only other way to get them is by asking for them specifically (`git fetch --tags`) or by updating the fetch refspec to add another line to your .git/config to grab them:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/python/cpython.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

BTW, you won't find the remotes tags under a scoped remote reference (`origin/tag-name`).  They're global by default and live in a single space and are pulled into the repo's local namespace directly (just `tag-name`).